# Add %age discount to Opencart product

Tags: opencart

I am new to opencart. I have a task at hand. I need to add few discounts to some products. There are two types of discounts that i have to add.

1. Fixed price. Like if something is of $10, i offer that at $8.
2. %age discount. Like I want to offer 50% off on the product.

What i found is that open cart has a discount tab in it's backend but it has options for only fixed price discount.

I have attached its snapshot for reference.

[image]

How can I add a percentage discount option?

Answer (score 1):

There is one small caveat in OpenCart's product administration: the **Discount** tab does not set a **sale price** but a **quantity discount**. That's why You need to set the *Quantity* there - it means how many products have to be bought for this (quantity) discount to be applied.

If You set these discounts on some product that has a base price $25:

- quantity 5, price $22.5
- quantity 10, price $20
- quantity 15, price $17.5

then you can see it in action if you display the product's detail - a table listing the quantity discounts should be displayed (depends on your template) and after adding different quantity of this product to your cart you'll realize the change of the price.

The other tab that you are looking for is **Special** where you can set only the fix *sales price*.

There is no possibility to set a percentage sales nor quantity discounts in the default OpenCart installation.